# Error when trying to build my Jekyll site

Tags: jekyll

Whenever I update my OS I start having trouble with Ruby and Jekyll. Current OS: OS X, 10.10.2. When I try to build my site this is the error I get:

```
Configuration file: /Users/MyName/Projects/blog/_config.yml
/Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- typogruby (LoadError)
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/MyName/Projects/blog/_plugins/enhanced_kramdown.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require_plugin_files'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:73:in `each'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:73:in `block in require_plugin_files'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:72:in `each'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:72:in `require_plugin_files'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:18:in `conscientious_require'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:79:in `setup'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:41:in `initialize'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `new'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `process'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mercenary-0.3.5/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I tried uninstalling jekyll, ruby,rvm and re-installing again.

My gem list & gem environment:

```
$gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.4)
blankslate (2.1.2.4)
bundler (1.9.4, 1.6.1)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
celluloid (0.16.0)
classifier-reborn (2.0.3)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
colorator (0.1)
execjs (2.5.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2, 1.3.1)
fast-stemmer (1.0.2)
ffi (1.9.8)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7, 1.2.4)
hitimes (1.2.2)
io-console (0.4.2)
jekyll (2.5.3)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.1)
jekyll-gist (1.2.1)
jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.3.0)
jekyll-watch (1.2.1)
json (1.8.1)
kramdown (1.6.0)
liquid (2.6.2)
listen (2.10.0)
mercenary (0.3.5)
minitest (5.6.0, 4.7.5)
parslet (1.5.0)
posix-spawn (0.3.11)
power_assert (0.2.3)
psych (2.0.13, 2.0.3)
pygments.rb (0.6.3)
rake (10.4.2, 10.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.2.0, 4.1.0)
redcarpet (3.2.3)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4, 1.4.3)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
safe_yaml (1.0.4)
sass (3.4.13)
test-unit (3.0.9, 2.1.1.0)
timers (4.0.1)
toml (0.1.2)
yajl-ruby (1.2.1)

$ gem env

RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
- RUBY VERSION: 2.1.1 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 76) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/dafnapresler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/dafnapresler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/dafnapresler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/dafnapresler/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-darwin-12
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1
 - /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
 - SHELL PATH:
   - /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin
   - /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin
   - /Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /usr/bin
   - /bin
   - /usr/sbin
   - /sbin
   - /Users/MyName/.rvm/bin
   - /usr/bin
   - /bin
   - /usr/sbin
   - /sbin
   - /usr/local/bin
   - /Users/MyName/.rvm/bin
   - /Users/MyName/bin
```

Here are my installations:

```
$ which jekyll
/Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/jekyll

$ which gem
/Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/gem

$ which ruby
/Users/MyName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
```

Would love any advice to get me out of this mess.

Comment: It's trying to load a plugin named "enhanced_kramdown", which requires a Gem named "typogruby". Neither of those are listed in your Gem list. Are you using a Gemfile to keep track of dependencies?

Comment: Thanks, Not using a gemfile to keep track of dependencies, how do I do that?

Comment: I installed typogruby but still I get the same error..

Comment: Read http://bundler.io/gemfile.html for how to use a Gemfile to manage dependencies. You need install Bundler first, and from then on you manage dependencies in the file and run `bundle install` when you modify the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Bundler to manage your application's dependencies.

You can install bundler using gem. If it is present, delete the `Gemfile.lock` file. Then run the command to check and fix dependencies:

```
> gem install bundler
> rm Gemfile.lock
> bundle install
```